# Style form field in class-based view in Django

Tags: django

I am using class-based views to create a form on a website. The code below is working so far. But I need to add a custom CSS class (`box-message`) to the `message` field so it can be styled correctly. How can I do that?

This is what I have accomplished so far.

```
# view.py ----

from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .models import CandidateInfo

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CandidateInfo
        fields = ("name", "email", "message")

class ContactView(CreateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    model = CandidateInfo
    template_name = "index_test.html"


# models.py ----

from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class CandidateInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    message = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("index_text")
```

And the template:

```
<form id="contact-us" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

{{ form.as_p }}

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="contact-button" value="Send" />
```

This is the generated HTML:

```
<p><label for="id_name">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="200" required="" id="id_name"></p>
<p><label for="id_email">Email:</label> <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="200" required="" id="id_email"></p>
<p><label for="id_message">Message:</label> <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="10" required="" id="id_message"></textarea></p>
```

**What I need is for the `textarea` tag to have a `box-message` class.**

Comment: I don't understand. Why you don't put your css directly from static?

Comment: It is in static. But the CSS class needs to be an attribute from message field in the form.

Comment: @seuling I edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['message'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'box-message'})

    class Meta:
    model = CandidateInfo
    fields = ("name", "email", "message")
```

Read more about this:
[Django Form Widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your postform,

```
class PostForm(form.ModelForm):
    message = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'#add class name', 'placeholder':'If you require'}))

    class Meta:
         #rest
```